# MongoDate is misbehaving

Tags: php, mongodb

Not sure what's happening, but mongodate is always initializing with 0 sec. Any thoughts as to what would cause that? date is correct on the server..

`$d = new MongoDate();
echo sprintf("%s -- %s \n",$d,$d->toDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i'));`

> 0.52000000 1037164 -- 1970-01-13 00:06

`$d = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-15 00:00:00"));
echo sprintf("%s -- %s \n",$d,$d->toDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i'));`

> 0.52000000 10371640.97600000 793214 -- 1970-01-10 04:20

Comment: update, it seems to be the toDateTime method that is actually misbehaving.. printing mongodate out gives me the correct epoch time..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well it seems that mongodate->todatestring just doesn't work.

So.... whatever.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Construct your datetime objects from MongoDate->sec, because #php

```
$d = new MongoDate();
$slugDate = new DateTime();
$slugDate->setTimestamp($d->sec);

echo sprintf("mongodate= %s \n",$d->toDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i'));
echo sprintf("datetime from mongo = %s \n",$slugDate->format('Y-m-d H:i'));
```

> $ mongodate= 1970-01-13 01:11
>
> $ datetime from mongo = 2015-10-06 16:47

Comment: well, they have a closed bug tracker, so bugger that. I believe the bug is on line 156 here:   https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/024c49c587e5b02d5375b9da2617c450fc5d6c3c/types/date.c     156: zval *datetime_object_ptr = &datetime_object; should be moved to after line 169